# how to submit a non-form element using angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let gasType of staffConfig.gasTypes">
        <td class="col-md-3">
          <input class="gas-name form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="gasType.name" name="gasName"
                 [disabled]="!isStaffEnabled">
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
        <img src="/assets/brand-icon.png">
        <span>Brands</span>
      </h3>
    </div>

    <!-- Table -->
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let brand of staffConfig.brands;let i = index;">
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="brand.name" name="brands"
                 [disabled]="!isStaffEnabled">
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</tab>
```

```
<button id="saveChangesBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save Changes</button>
```

I want to bind the "save" button to a method in the component. So I changed:

```
<button id="saveChangesBtn" type="button" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(registrationForm.value) class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save Changes</button>
```

but then, if that's not a `<form>` how do I bind  the fields  to a model?
In other words how can I send these fields to the server?
I have to read them from the component and  then assemble an object.
But how can I access the non-form model  like `registrationForm.value`?

Comment: `(ngSubmit)` is for `<form>s` use `(click)` instead

Comment: and how do i relate in the component to the ui text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ngModel` outside of the `<form>` you must specify `[ngModelOptions]={standalone:true}`.

**Template**

```
<div class="not-a-form">

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.foo" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.bar" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />

    <button type="button" (click)="save(model)"> Send </button>

</div>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
selector: 'selector',
...
})

class SomeComponent {
 model: any = {};

  save(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```